# Workflow does not execute properly, but no exception is thrown

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have working with Microsoft wf sample projects: WF_WCF_Samples\WF\Application\VisualWorkflowTracking\CS
This sample project runs a wf4 simulation.

The workflow has an input bool argument.

Currently I have two problems.

First problem:

If I enter a value into the argument (workflow designer), I don't get any exception when the code runs but the simulation does not execute.

I modified the code and tried getting the collection of arguments.  I then add them to a Dictionary which is then passed to the Invoke Method.  This approach does not get me any error but it does not launches the process.  I think that the value of the argument is not being passed properly to the Dictionary.  Below is the code:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((context) =>
{

    bool noArguments = false;

    var serviceManager = this.WorkflowDesigner.Context.Services;

    Dictionary<string, object> retval = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var modelService = serviceManager.GetService<ModelService>();
    var rootModelItem = modelService.Root;

    var properties = rootModelItem.Properties["Properties"];
    if (properties == null) noArguments = true;

    var propertiesCollection = properties.Collection;
    if (propertiesCollection == null) noArguments = true;
    if (propertiesCollection.Count == 0) noArguments = true;

    foreach (var p in propertiesCollection)
    {
        var d = p.GetCurrentValue() as DynamicActivityProperty;
        if (d != null)
        {
            var name = d.Name;
            dynamic inArgument = d.Value;

            try
            {
                var val = inArgument.Expression.Value;
                retval.Add(name, val);
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Variable: " + d.Name + " Value is Empty", "Variable Error",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

    }

    //Invoking the Workflow Instance with Input Arguments
    if (noArguments)
    {
        instance.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        //this line below does raise any error but it does not run the process.
        //instance.Invoke(retval, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));  

//this line below works as long as in the workflow designer the argument value is left blank
        instance.Invoke(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "decisionVar", "hello" } }, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
    }


    //This is to remove the final debug adornment
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render
        , (Action)(() =>
    {
        this.WorkflowDesigner.DebugManagerView.CurrentLocation = new SourceLocation(this.WorkFlowFile,1,1,1,10);
        //this.WorkflowDesigner.DebugManagerView.CurrentLocation = new SourceLocation("Workflow.xaml",1,1,1,10);
    }));

}));
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that an exception is being thrown and terminating the thread that is doing the work.  You may want to surround the whole thing with a try/catch block and log the exception.

Comment: Hello Ron, thanks for taking the time to comment on my question.

Comment: Hello Ron, thanks for taking the time to comment on my question. I downloaded the MS Samples on WCF and WF. Open the project WF_WCF_Samples\WF\Application\VisualWorkflowTracking\CS VisualWorkflowTracking.sln Do F5, then while in debug, on the Application click "File" then "Run Workflow".... You will see that the simulaton runs. Now, try this: Stop debug, in design mode open the workflow, there is an argument called "desicionVar". Enter a value in the "default value". Either True or False. Run it again and you will see that the simulation does not run

Comment: In the sample code there is a line in the "WorkflowDesignerHost.xaml.cs" file that pass a hard coded value to the default value.

The line is :
instance.Invoke(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "decisionVar", true } }, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));


I don't understand why the simulation does not run after you enter a "default Value" to the decisionVar argument in the workflow designer?
I don't see any error while compiling nor while executing

Hope this clarify my question.  Please let me know if you can replicate what I described here.

Comment: When I run this sample, the workflow runs both with and without a default value for the decisionVar in argument.  If you check the debug output window you should see tracking records and the output from the writeline activity.